Já houve algum tempo verbal que deixou de existir no Português?
Em outras línguas, como é o caso do espanhol, já houve tempos verbais (neste exemplo específico, o futuro do subjuntivo ou o pretérito mais-que-perfeito simples) que desapareceram total ou parcialmente, tanto na linguagem corrente quanto na linguagem culta. Então, fica a pergunta:

No português, já houve algum tempo verbal que deixou de ser usado?

Alguns provavelmente usarão o pretérito mais-que-perfeito simples como exemplo, mas fato é que ainda se pode encontrá-lo em diversos textos de linguagem mais culta produzidos nos dias de hoje…
Obrigado desde já!

Na época do galego-português (circa 1200), acho que tinha uns 2 que sumiram. Até o século XIX, tinha o pretérito mais-que-perfeito anterior. Porém, acho que uma das coisas mais similares do português antigo com o moderno, sãs as conjugações verbais.

Em geral, não. Todos os tempos latinos que não se encontram na língua hoje foram perdidos na fase proto-românica, não em alguma fase portuguesa posterior. Mas é bem provável que haja algumas perífrases verbais exclusivas ao período medieval.

@Quaestoria Você teria uma referência sobre isso? E algum lugar onde se possam encontrar todos os tempos verbais latinos para fins de comparação?

Pelo que pude encontrar, de fato, nenhum tempo verbal deixou de existir. Porém, ao longo da história da Língua Portuguesa, houve algumas alterações em determinadas conjugações. Por exemplo, no futuro do subjuntivo, formas como “se eu fizeres” e “se ele fizere” apareciam junto às variações mais próximas da conjugação atual (“fizer”).
Outro exemplo são os verbos no presente do indicativo no Português Arcaico, que podiam ter a terminação "-edes" ou "-edes" para a segunda pessoa do plural – vós amaredes (em vez do atual vós amais).

Nota sobre o -des: Ainda existe em galego, e sobrevive em alguns verbos irregulares, principalmente aqueles em que uma consoante nasal ou líquida precede o '-d-', como 'ter': vós tendes. Também se o vê sempre no futuro subjuntivo/conjuntivo.
